# Separar timestamp en diferentes columnas

Tags: sql, sqlite

Tengo una columna que es un Timestamp con el siguiente formato: "YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-SS". Puedo dividir esta columna en dos columnas(una columna para los años y otra para los meses)  y eliminar lo demás debido a que no lo necesito?

El formato de timestamp que manejo es el siguiente: '1999-12-31 23:59:59'; y quiero que quede de la siguiente manera(una vez eliminados los datos irrelevantes):
[image: Ejemplo]

Estoy trabajando online con SQLite(https://sqliteonline.com/). Sé que no es lo más óptimo pero por el momento no necesito más. Las tablas las estoy alimentando con un Insert.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. La respuesta es si, pero primero muéstranos que has intentado. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos? por favor, agregalo en las etiquetas

Comment: @kemilbeltre es conveniente que esperemos a que nos confirme el PO el motor de base de datos, estas especulando entre MySQL y Oracle.

Comment: @Sal toda la razón (lo he eliminado).

Comment: @Daniel, además de lo ya dicho, sugiero que agregues un pequeño ejemplo de como quieres que queden los datos en tu tabla, con 2 o 3 filas es suficiente, con las columnas relevantes. Un saludo y bienvenido.

Comment: Hola @DjCrazy, mis disculpas por no haber añadido lo que he intentado pero es que debido a mis escasos conocimientos todo lo que he visto en internet no he sabido aplicarlo y por eso me he decidido a abrir este hilo.

Comment: @jachguate añadido ejemplo. Disculpa por mis errores a la hora de abrir el hilo.

Answer (score 3):

En `sqlite` puedes usar la función [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

```
select strftime('%Y', '2021-06-22 18:44:34') as Año,
       strftime('%m', '2021-06-22 18:44:34') as Mes

Año     Mes
2021    06
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Donde has puesto la fecha('2021-06-22 18:44:34') no se puede poner el nombre de la columna para que extraiga año y mes sobre todas las filas?

Comment: Daniel, si es un ejemplo, ahí va la columna con la fecha/hora

Comment: Me refiero que al final tengo todos estos registros:
'2015-05-11 18:44:34'
'2015-05-15 18:44:34'
'2015-09-14 18:44:34'
Hay alguna posibilidad de no tener que hacer lo siguiente y llamar a la columna y que extraiga año y mes de toda la columna TIMESTAMP?
select strftime('%Y', '2021-06-22 18:44:34') as Año,
       strftime('%m', '2021-06-22 18:44:34') as Mes,
strftime('%Y', ''2015-05-15 18:44:34'') as Año,
       strftime('%m', ''2015-05-15 18:44:34'') as Mes,
strftime('%Y', ''2015-09-14 18:44:34') as Año,
       strftime(''2015-09-14 18:44:34'') as Mes,

Comment: Claro, pero pensé que entendías que mi respuesta es un ejemplo que lo tienes que trasladar a tu escenario, no sé como se llama la tabla ni la columna, no lo has publicado, básicamente es hacer algo así `select strftime('%Y', tu_columna) as Año from tu_tabla`